# Windows Phone 8.1 ListViewItem default XAML style ignored (generic.xaml)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, listviewitem

I added a ListView to a XAML page, and want to use the default styling for the ListViewItems so that when an item is selected, the border is highlighted and the checkbox glyph is visible.

However, I cannot seem to achieve this; clicking an item to select it makes no visual change on the screen. I verified that the item is being selected by handling the SelectionChanged event and setting a break point. the item is selected, but visually nothing is different.

I did have a ListViewItem style defined that overrides the stretch values, and thought perhaps that was killing all the default styles, but removing every custom style that mentions ListViewItem or ListView still leaves it without the default styles.

I looked at the generic.xaml and the default styles there with the selected states and the checkmark glyph are there, but they just don't seem to be applied.

I can even go into blend and edit the ItemContainerStyle to create a copy, and it pulls in everything from generic.xaml and assigns it to the template. But still, those styles are ignored and I do not see the glyph,even in blend when I select the different visual states like "selected.

I changed backgrounds just in case it was invisible due to having the same color, but it just doesn't appear to be there...

What might be causing the default styles to be ignored, even when they are copied over and assigned directly?

Answer (score 0):

so after comparing the generated styles both from Blend in creating a copy and the generic.xaml styles, it appears this is a bug caused by a bad style definition.

The ListViewItem style in the generic.xaml differs from the ListViewItem template in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709921.aspx

specifically, the documented template listed above defines an additional animation in the storyboard for the "Selected" and "SelectedUnfocused" states:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            Duration="0" To="1" />
```

Adding this section to the style fixed the problem, and the visual state is now as expected.

So it appears that the solution here would be to either add that missing section, or better yet, simply use the documented template as your base in Windows Phone for ListViewItem, as the default one in generic.xaml is not complete.

I don't know if this is by design but it sure feels like a bug.